# Problems building libmemcached on Mac OSX (and Mint, and CentOS)

Tags: c, build, memcached, client, libmemcached

Downloaded the tarball from https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/+download/libmemcached-1.0.12.tar.gz (linked to from libmemcached.org).  Ran the usual **./configure + make** protocol, got a number of errors related to implicitly converting 64-bit value to 32-bit, and eventually a failure to find event.h.

Earlier, tried installing on Mint (*./libtool: line 1125: g++: command not found*) and CentOS (*./libmemcached-1.0/memcached.h:46:27: error: tr1/cinttypes: No such file or directory*)

I'm not too bright when it comes to debugging this, but I'm very used to ./configure + make "just working".  Anybody able to help?

Thanks,
Chap

Answer (score 0):

I meet it yet. And, I found it :

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/20635

In the page, the error been found is a libmemcahed bug that had been report as  https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1216521